# Explanation for Green-Kubo relation

Tags: correlation-functions, viscosity

I have a set of data $(t,P_{xy})$ with the stress-tensor evolution, $P_{ij}(t)$, and I want to compute the viscosity via Green-Kubo relation. The problem is that depending of the reference I find the following expressions (I suppose isotropic system)
$$ \eta = \frac{V}{k_B T} \int_0^\infty <P_{xy}(0) \cdot P_{xy}(t)>\cdot dt  \quad\quad \quad \quad \quad  \quad  \eta = \frac{V}{k_B T} \int_0^\infty C_{P_{xy},P_{xy}}(t)\cdot dt   $$
but as far as I know
$$C_{P_{xy},P_{xy}}(t)= <P_{xy}(0) \cdot P_{xy}(t)> - <P_{xy}(0)> \cdot <P_{xy}(t)>$$
So I don't understand what expression I have to use to compute it, and I don't fully understand the role of $P_{xy}(0)$ in this expression if it is a constant, isn't it? Maybe it is just a but understanding in the notation

I have check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation), but I don't understand if I have to use auto-correlation or auto-covariance function here, or in this case should give me the same result? Should I normalize the function?

Can someone give some explanation to compute it? Because I don't know how I have to do this auto-correlation/auto-covariance function/average of the stress tensor